# Which kind of data fits for ARIMA model

Tags: arima

My data is like that:

[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,9,6,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

I understand that data characterized by stationary fluctuations are suitable for ARIMA modeling. However, the data I have are stable and may not be compatible with the ARIMA model. Could you provide some advice on how to proceed with this data? Would adding white noise be beneficial, or should I consider alternative modeling approaches that are better suited for stable data?